# Why Does `libusb_bulk_transfer' Return 0?

Tags: c, linux, embedded, libusb

I am using libusb-1.0. Sometimes when I call:

```
    int rc = libusb_bulk_transfer(handle_,
                                  EP_IN_ADDR,
                                  (unsigned char *)buf_,
                                  64,
                                  &read_,
                                  0);
```

it returns rc = 0 (no error) and read_ = 0 (zero number of bytes received). But I have specified infinite timeout (last argument), so isn't `libusb_bulk_transfer' supposed to block until I have some data?

Comment: Have you tried running libusb_clear_halt(); before that code to clear any halts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sometimes, it returns rc = 0 (no error) and read_ == 0 (zero number of bytes received).

A bulk endpoint can send you packets with *zero* bytes of data, called zero packets. This is not an error condition.

Comment: That makes sense. Search engine told me that a sender can send a USB packet less than the end-point size to signify end of sequence. I should probably pose this as a new question, but do you have an idea, why an Arduino CDC to ACM serial to USB would send such zero-length packets?